# How to view only UA (update after, +U) data in a table created by upsert-kafka in fllink

Tags: apache-flink

When the result of working with Upsert-kafka occurs as a kafka topic, both UB (update before, -U) and UA (update after, +U) are monitored.

I want to put only one updated line into a kafka topic‍♀️

Does anyone know how?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jYCA.png)

I want to know how to save only +(UPDATE_AFTER) from above table to kafka topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by buffering records and delaying sending them to Kafka, so that only the final result gets emitted. You would need to set `sink.buffer-flush.max-rows` and `sink.buffer-flush.interval`. This is also documented at https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/upsert-kafka/#sink-buffer-flush-max-rows